# Gulp not compiling valid Sass

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp-sass

I have valid Sass which is not compiling. It gives me the following error.

```
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
source\assets\sass\components\_college-footer.scss
Error: Invalid CSS after ".home": expected "{", was "&"
"&" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.
```

Below is the Sass that is trying to be complied:

```
.footer-wrapper{
        margin:0;
        border:0;
        border-top: 1px solid $light-gray;

        .home& {
            border-top:0;
        }
```

When I fix an issue, another just occurs. I'm thinking that there must be an issue with the Sass Gulp version.

Node version v4.4.7

NPM version v3.10.3

Gulp version v3.9.1

Reinstalled a number of times and the same result every time.

Comment: Your SASS file definitely has a syntax error. What I learned over the years is that the compiler is one way or another is always right.

Comment: Colleagues have complied theirs without any issue. I'm 100% sure it is to do with my setup rather than the SASS.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with `.home&`? Try using `&.home`

Comment: Also you are missing a closing bracket at the end

Comment: I'd still put my bets you your code being fishy. Maybe just a space, maybe other whitespace charcter.

Start deleting various rules and see if it compiles.

UPDATE: now I see your code. The & should be before the dot.

Comment: using the ampersand on the right allows the selector with the ampersand to become the parent selector. The resulting css would be .home . footer-wrapper {}. Take a look at https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/#article-header-id-5. As I also mentioned if I do move the ampersand I will just get another issue with a different part of the SaSS

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax seems invalid, not sure why it's working on your co-workers' computers, perhaps their setup is the one the is wrong.

Try the following:

```
.footer-wrapper {
        margin:0;
        border:0;
        border-top: 1px solid $light-gray;
        &.home {
            border-top:0;
        }
}
```

Hope this helps!